# How do I achieve an average star with react and font awesome?

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is the result I want to achieve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvcsf.png)

and here is my code base:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const UserRatingDisplay = ({ ratingsArr }) => {
  const [userRatings, setUserRatings] = useState([]);
  const [skillAvg, setSkillAvg] = useState("no ratings yet");
  const [teamAvg, setTeamAvg] = useState("no ratings yet");

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateAvg = () => {
      // Sum the skillset ratings
      const skillsetRatingSum = userRatings.reduce((sum, ratingObj) => {
        return sum + parseInt(ratingObj.skillset_rating, 10);
      }, 0);

      // Sum the team ratings
      const teamRatingSum = userRatings.reduce((sum, ratingObj) => {
        return sum + parseInt(ratingObj.team_member_rating, 10);
      }, 0);

      // Determine the averages
      const skillsetRatingAvg = skillsetRatingSum / userRatings.length;
      const teamRatingAvg = teamRatingSum / userRatings.length;

      // Set the string values in state to render
      setSkillAvg(`${Math.round(skillsetRatingAvg)} / 10`);
      setTeamAvg(`${Math.round(teamRatingAvg)} / 10`);
    };

    if (userRatings.length > 0) {
      calculateAvg();
    }
  }, [userRatings]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ratingsArr.length > 0) {
      setUserRatings(ratingsArr);
    }
  }, [ratingsArr]);

  return (
    <div className="container--user_ratings">
      <div className="container--user_rating_one">
        <h5 className="header header--user_rating">Average Skillset Rating</h5>
        <p className="text text--user_rating">{skillAvg}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="container--user_rating_two">
        <h5 className="header header--user_rating">Average Teamplayer Rating</h5>
        <p className="text text--user_rating">{teamAvg}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserRatingDisplay;
```

This is what I have right now on my project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e41Ja.png)

How can I achieve this look with css and react by using fontawesome?

Comment: Are you trying to roll your own, or would something like [Rating](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/) from Material-UI work for you? What have you already tried on your own to implement a rating component/UI?

Comment: Thanks! I will try out the Rating from Material UI

Comment: @DrewReese How can I make the rating appear as a result?

Comment: I can help, but I'll need a bit more context around your last question. What do you mean "make the rating appear as a result"?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you so much for helping me out. So I'm using `<Rating name="half-rating" />` but it's like im rating other people. The result I want to achieve is if the rating is 6/10 It will appear 6 stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

If you are using the `Rating` component from Material-UI and you want it to be static then you really only need to specify a `value` prop and a `readOnly` prop. You can pass other props to refine the display.

```
<Rating
  value={skillAvg} // <-- the rating value
  precision={0.5} // <-- display half stars
  readOnly // <-- make read only, user can't interact
  max={10} // <-- make out of 10 stars
/>
```

Other issues:

1. Using `parseInt` truncates any fractional ratings, in other words `2.5` or `"2.5"` become `2`. Perhaps this is by design but if your "ratings system" doesn't allow for fractional values then that should be sanitized when rating data is inputted or created. You don't want to strip out fractional values before computing the sum. I like to use `Number` to convert strings to a number type.
2. The `Rating` component works with number types, but you are stringifying the average result value, so nothing was being displayed into the `Rating` component.
3. Storing the passed `ratingsArr` prop into local component state is a anti-pattern in React, you can just compute the averages directly from the prop. This also saves a rerender now that the component doesn't need to wait a render cycle to get the updated `userRatings` state.

Code:

```
const UserRatingDisplay = ({ ratingsArr }) => {
  const [skillAvg, setSkillAvg] = useState(null);
  const [teamAvg, setTeamAvg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateAvg = () => {
      // Sum the skillset ratings
      const skillsetRatingSum = ratingsArr.reduce((sum, ratingObj) => {
        return sum + Number(ratingObj.skillset_rating);
      }, 0);

      // Sum the team ratings
      const teamRatingSum = ratingsArr.reduce((sum, ratingObj) => {
        return sum + Number(ratingObj.team_member_rating);
      }, 0);

      // Determine the averages
      const skillsetRatingAvg = skillsetRatingSum / ratingsArr.length;
      const teamRatingAvg = teamRatingSum / ratingsArr.length;

      // Set the string values in state to render
      setSkillAvg(skillsetRatingAvg);
      setTeamAvg(teamRatingAvg);
    };

    if (ratingsArr.length) {
      calculateAvg();
    } else {
      setSkillAvg(null);
      setTeamAvg(null);
    }
  }, [ratingsArr]);

  return (
    <div className="container--user_ratings">
      <div className="container--user_rating_one">
        <h5 className="header header--user_rating">Average Skillset Rating</h5>
        {skillAvg !== null ? (
          <>
            <Rating value={skillAvg} precision={0.5} readOnly max={10} />
            <p className="text text--user_rating">{skillAvg.toFixed(2)}/10</p>
          </>
        ) : (
          "no ratings yet"
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="container--user_rating_two">
        <h5 className="header header--user_rating">
          Average Teamplayer Rating
        </h5>
        {teamAvg !== null ? (
          <>
            <Rating value={teamAvg} precision={0.5} readOnly max={10} />
            <p className="text text--user_rating">{teamAvg.toFixed(2)}/10</p>
          </>
        ) : (
          "no ratings yet"
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-do-i-achieve-an-average-star-with-react-and-font-awesome]

[image]

Note: This solution isn't as DRY as it could possibly be, the `Rating` and associated labeling is repeated. It is a trivial matter to refactor this into a React component though.

```
const TenStarRating = ({ value }) => (
  {value !== null ? (
    <>
      <Rating value={value} precision={0.5} readOnly max={10} />
      <p className="text text--user_rating">{value.toFixed(2)}/10</p>
    </>
  ) : (
    "no ratings yet"
  )}
);
```

Then the original code above reduces to a more readable

```
<div className="container--user_rating_one">
  <h5 className="header header--user_rating">Average Skillset Rating</h5>
  <TenStarRating value={skillAvg} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem.

Comment: 6.7 is not being represented correctly, is it? So that solution can only handle halves and round numbers

Comment: @JoséAlvarez It is. Note that the `Rating` component is using a precision of `0.5`, so yes, it's currently rounding to the nearest half number. `6.7` was selected on purpose to highlight this rounding precision. Adjust the precision value and note the difference in rendered result. Though, playing around with different values, it seems the `Rating` component has issues with values that don't result in even divisions into `1`. For example, `0.25` works, while `0.3` does not.